# How do I get a number with two digits after the decimal using double type numbers in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm coding a simple calculator, and it needs to be displaying 2 digits after the decimal, but I can't figure it out. The rest of the program works perfectly, and so does the quotient button, but it's just displaying too many digits after the decimal.  Here's what I have:

```
private double _leftop = 0;
private double _rightop = 0;
private double _quotient = 0;

    private void BtnQuotient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Double.TryParse(TxtLeftOperand.Text, out _leftop) == true &&     Double.TryParse(TxtRightOperand.Text, out _rightop) == true)
        {
            _quotient = _leftop / _rightop;
            TxtResult.Text = Convert.ToString(_quotient);
        }
        else
        {
            TxtResult.Text = "Error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to _display_ with two digits, or convert to two digits?  The former you can use a `Format` on the output to a string, the latter as was posted as answer below, you can use `Math.Round()`.

Comment: `TextResult.Text = _quotient.ToString("f2");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TxtResult.Text = (Math.Round(_quotient, 2)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.Round()` method.

```
Math.Round(value, numOfDigits);
```